# What means (3) in fnc(3)?

Tags: c, libunwind

Looking libunwind.h docs(https://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/docs.html),

All functions(ex.libunwind-ia64(3), unw_get_proc_name(3)) have fnc name + (3).
What means (3)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number refers to the section in the Linux manual that the documentation for these functions reside in.

When using the `man` command to look up documentation you can optionally specify the section, for example `man unw_get_proc_name` or `man 3 unw_get_proc_name`.  You would need to specify the section if there was a manual entry with that name in a different section.

This practice goes back to the UNIX days.  I've personally seen it going back to Solaris 2.5.1 (1994-1995), but it's probably older than that.

Comment: Specifically, section 3 is for library functions.  You can see the list of sections in `man man`.